# htaccess working on www., not working without www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do have an centos/apache server, with this htaccess file. When I visit the site via www.example.com I'm correctly redirected to testsite.com, when I go to example.com it seems like the server read the htaccess from another server (the old one of the domain, I think, but I don't have access to it). Here's the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^myip  
RewriteRule .* http://www.testsite.it [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way it's set alias in your domain zone configuration that redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`. It should be there but for some reason its not, I gues. Check it anyway.

Comment: Hi, so the problem is in DNS records? I do not have access to it unfortunatly, so I've to ask, but I would prefer to ask only if there's something like 90% of possibility that this is the reason. Is there anything else I could check? Thanks. What happens when I'll install https certificate?

Comment: Also, the problem is that, like in htaccess, I'd like to work on example.com urls rather than www.example.com

Comment: That's only one reason I can explain your case - domain configuration. Any way if you will write alias it should solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean, adding this into httpd.conf? <VirtualHost *>
  ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Also, it's strange that the second part of my htaccess code is something like ignored, as it doesn't redirect www. to non-www...

Comment: No. The alias is in domain zone configuration file at DNS. If your domain services by some hosting provider it must be in your admin panel.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any idea instead about the reason why the rewrite from www. to non-www in the htacces is ignored? It works fine on another website.

Comment: Check have you access to htaccess at all if you type www. If so maybe you should change order of rules.